# VideoView from WebView Wont Play Video?

Tags: android, url, video, webview, android-videoview

My app currently uses a WebView and then using a WebChromeClient and onShowCustomView goes to a VideoView for Videos. HOWEVER, I am unsure as to how to get the correct link when I click on the video? It comes up saying that the video cannot be played, but it is because I am not passing it a video at all. How can I get the URL of a link that is clicked? Any help?

This is the Activity with the WebView:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.mnwv_main);

    myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
    myWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    myWebView.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);     

    myWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {  

    public void onShowCustomView(View view, CustomViewCallback callback) {  
    super.onShowCustomView(view, callback); 
    videoURL = myWebView.getUrl();
    in= new Intent(MNWVMainPage.this,MainPageVideoHandler.class);
    startActivity(in); }  
    });       

    myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    myWebView.loadUrl("http://www.meanwhileinwv.com"); 
}
```

If I click on a video, this activity starts:

```
public class MainPageVideoHandler extends Activity {

VideoView myVideoView;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.video_player);

   myVideoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoview);
   MediaController mediaController = new MediaController(this);
   mediaController.setAnchorView(myVideoView);
   String video = (MNWVMainPage.videoURL);
   myVideoView.setMediaController(mediaController);
   myVideoView.setVideoPath(video);
   myVideoView.start();


   myVideoView.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {         
     @Override  
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {  
        mp.stop();
        myVideoView.stopPlayback();
        setContentView(R.layout.mnwv_main);  
        }  
   });  

   myVideoView.setOnErrorListener(new OnErrorListener() {  
        @Override  
        public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) {  
            return false;  
        }  
   });        
  }  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should implement [`shouldOverrideUrlLoading(..)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html#shouldOverrideUrlLoading%28android.webkit.WebView,%20java.lang.String%29) in your `WebViewClient`. This gives you the chance to intercept URL loading and show your video view.